# Creating timeout and deadlock bug in MySQL on purpose

Tags: mysql, timeout, mysql-workbench, database-deadlocks

I'm currently working with some databases and I'm trying to manually create bugs for them so that I can go about fixing them. I'm not sure if I will have any issues fixing the bugs yet, but I'm not really sure how to create the bugs in the first place.

Instead of the terminal I am using MySQL Workbench and I am trying to create a scenario where I would experience a timeout error and a deadlock error.

I know that If I were to make a timeout error in-terminal I would login twice to create two instances and then make modifications to the same database under two people and try to commit.

You can already do so much with MySQL Workbench I was wondering if there was any feasible way for me to replicate this action using only code in the workbench rather than go through the hassle of constantly having two instances of my terminal open.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot generate a lock timeout or a deadlock with just one connection to MySQL open.

But you can open the same connection profile twice in MySQL Workbench. You can open two (or more) tabs, and each has its own connection. Then you can start a transaction in each tab and experiment with lock timeouts and deadlocks.

I demonstrated this by creating a table `test.emp1`:

```
CREATE TABLE `emp1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO `emp1` SET `name`='me', `date`=CURRENT_DATE();
INSERT INTO `emp1` SET `name`='you', `date`=CURRENT_DATE();
```

Then I opened two tabs to my local MySQL instance in Workbench.

In tab one, I ran:

```
begin;
update emp1 set name='me2' where id=1;
select sleep(10);
update emp1 set name='you2' where id=2;
```

In the second tab, I ran:

```
begin;
update emp1 set name='you2' where id=2;
select sleep(10);
update emp1 set name='me2' where id=1;
```

Click execute in the first tab and then before the sleep(10) finishes, click execute in the second tab.

[image]

Voila! Deadlock on the second tab. The transaction on the first tab succeeded.

Personally, I find it nicer to do this with terminal windows, because I can arrange them side-by-side instead of viewing one at a time in tabs.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will try this out and see if it works.

Comment: @SmilodonFatalis I'm glad to help. As a reminder, it is customary on Stack Overflow to give an upvote to answers that helped you, and check the "Accept" checkmark for the one that helped the most.

Comment: I did upvote you, but I have less than 15 reputation. So the upvote cannot be seen publicly.